# Django Context Processors not being called

Tags: django

I've got a context processor which is supposed to inject a list of offices into the template to be displayed in the global footer. The context processor isn't even being called.

Django version is 2.1.

```
(.env) ~/staging/ $ cat core/settings.py
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'contact.context_processors.offices',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
(.env) ~/staging/ $ cat contact/context_processors.py
from . import models

def offices(request):
    raise Exception('Testing: This got called')

    offices = models.Office.objects.order_by('order')

    return {
        'offices': offices,
    }
```

There's no exceptions being thrown and no warnings or error messages in the console.

Comment: The only reason I can think why its not calling your context processor is that the server hasn't restarted.

Comment: Please show your view. Are you using the render shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Sachin Kukreja was right... I needed to restart my server. I thought that autoreloading the code would cause this to work, but it didn't.

(Sachin, if you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it so you get credit.)